# Authorization and Authentication For Front and backend

Tags: .net, angular, azure, authentication

In my Project, I have Angular as Frontend and dotnet 6 as my Backend. My application is hosted in Azure. I want that only user from active directory can assess the application. I used this libraries in frontend:

```
 "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.1.2",
 "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.22.1",
```

I can get the token with 'msalService.acquireTokenSilent' and put it into my header. Now my question is how to communicate with backend?
Should my Backend seperatly connect with TenantId and ClientId and CallbackPath to Auze like this example:

> builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
> .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

or should my backend only get the token and check if it is validate? like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

any clue? or some reference?
My backend give my token no access...

Answer (score 0):

If you only need Public Client authentication, you could simply authenticate the user in the front end, then verify passed tokens in the backend.

My application, like many others, is "hybrid". This means that I perform Confidential Client authentication on the backend, retrieve a SPA Code from the backend, and then use that SPA code to perform Public Client authentication on the front end. I go into my detailed rationale for the "hybrid" approach here:
https://mindline.com/august-1-authenticating-enterprise-apps-in-2023/

And go into detail on the frontend architecture here:
https://mindline.com/august-15-authenticating-apps-in-2023-a-closer-look/

Best of luck!

Comment: First of all tnx for your fast response :D. In Azure Active Directory I created an App registrations, there under Single-Page-Application I added my redirect url, and under App roles I created two roles. Admin and Member.  In Anglar using MSAL I can get verified and also get the token. Now I want to know, should the backend only read the given token or also retrieve a token from Azure and compare the tokens.

Comment: There are reasons to do both. If your needs can be met by Public Client authentication, then you can simply verify that token on the backend. If you want Confidential Client authentication, then I would perform authentication on the backend first, and THEN use the SPA code approach detailed here: https://mindline.com/august-15-authenticating-apps-in-2023-a-closer-look/. If you want to read about why you might want to perform Confidential Client authentication, I cover that here: https://mindline.com/august-1-authenticating-enterprise-apps-in-2023/

Comment: Something that is not clear to me is how to do the authentication first on backend. The user call first the Frontend. My frondend has no login, because all the pages are protected. that means the user should instantly get verified. How can I do the authentication first on backend? My Angular project is not inside the backend but is a seperate application

Comment: Ah yes, you would need to have at least one page unprotected on the front end to redirect an authentication request to the backend. However, if you don't need any Confidential Client authentication to be performed by the backend, you don't need to do this.

Comment: Aha, now I understand. I also used PublicClientApplication in my frontend, but actually I need the confidential. Does the @azure/msal-browser in Angular also supprot the confidential one? If not, you mean there is no way but to have a login page unprotected? and if the user want to login? should the frontend get this values bring to backend and there do the authentication? is this save? that the user give his/her credentials in our portal instead of redirect to microsoft?

Comment: Ah ok, the JavaScript MSAL libraries only support Public Client authentication, not Confidential Client authentication. This is because they can't be trusted to securely store a secret. To perform Confidential Client authentication, you will need to allow the user to trigger a redirect to the Microsoft Identity Web authentication endpoint (something like <yourServer>/Microsoft/Account/SignIn) which will prompt the user for credentials. My article here goes through this in detail: https://mindline.com/august-15-authenticating-apps-in-2023-a-closer-look/.

Comment: That means, I should get the username and password in a page created by myself and securely send it to backend and there do the confidential authentication?

Comment: No. That would be bad! You should have an unprotected page or a page that has an authenticated and unauthenticated version (msal-react let's you create pages like this). The unauthenticated version of your page should allow the user to indicate they want to login. Then your page should redirect the user to the Login screens that are built in to Microsoft Identity Web. Those screens will collect the credentials, prompt for MFA, do the device checks, etc. etc, If you follow my steps, you should redirect the user to <your server>/Microsoft/Account/SignIn to get the process going.

Comment: you mean in the unprotected page there is a login button that call not the backend but Microsoft login page?

Comment: Yes exactly. And then your back end can process callbacks from Microsoft Identity Web as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/web-apps-apis/authorization-codes#getting-tokens-by-authorization-code-in-msalnet